# I need some advice about what is causing a type error in my Game-Of-Life script

Tags: javascript, conways-game-of-life

So i am making a Game Of Life just for fun and practice but I am getting a `TypeError: cell.computeNeighborsCoords is not a function` and i just cant figure what is the cause. I've been at it for a while so maybe i am overlooking something simple.

I am looping through a grid which is an array of objects and calling a method of each object that is supposed to calculate all possible neighbor coords of a given cell. However, when i call the method, i seem to be getting the aforementioned error.

Help is much appreciated!

## Cell.js

```
export class Cell {
    constructor(x, y, resolution, state) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.sx = x * resolution;
        this.sy = y * resolution;
        this.w = resolution;
        this.h = resolution;
        this.state = state;
    }

    findCellByCoords(grid, x, y) {

        // LeftTop ox - 1, oy - 1
        // Left    ox - 1, oy
        // BLeft   ox - 1, oy + 1
        // Bottom  ox      oy + 1
        // BRight  ox + 1, oy + 1
        // Right   ox + 1, oy
        // RightTo ox + 1, oy - 1

        for(var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for(var j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                let cell = grid[i][j];
                if(cell.x == x && cell.y == y) return cell;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }    

    getTotalAliveNeighbors(cellCollection) {
        return cellCollection.reduce((acc, next) => {
            return acc += next.state;
        }, 0)
    }

    computeNeighborsCoords() {
        let ox = this.x;
        let oy = this.y;

        // LeftTop ox - 1, oy - 1
        // Left    ox - 1, oy
        // BLeft   ox - 1, oy + 1
        // Bottom  ox      oy + 1
        // BRight  ox + 1, oy + 1
        // Right   ox + 1, oy
        // RightTo ox + 1, oy - 1

        this.neighborCoords = [
            {
                x: ox - 1,
                y: oy - 1
            },
            {
                x: ox - 1,
                y: oy
            },
            {
                x: ox - 1,
                y: oy + 1
            },
            {
                x: ox,
                y: oy + 1
            },
            {
                x: ox + 1,
                y: oy + 1
            },
            {
                x: ox + 1,
                y: oy
            },
            {
                x: ox + 1,
                y: oy - 1
            },
            {
                x: ox,
                y: oy - 1
            }
        ];

        // neighborCoordsArr.forEach((neighborCoords) => {
        //     let x = (neighborCoords.x + maxCellsPerRowCol) % maxCellsPerRowCol;
        //     let y = (neighborCoords.y + maxCellsPerRowCol) % maxCellsPerRowCol;
        //     let foundNeighbor = this.findCellByCoords(grid, x, y);

        //     neighbors.push(foundNeighbor);
        // })

        // return neighbors;
    }
}
```

## App.js

```
import { Cell } from "/Cell.js"
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

var cachedCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
cachedCanvas.width = canvas.width;
cachedCanvas.height = canvas.height;
var cachedCtx = cachedCanvas.getContext("2d");

let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let grid,
    rows,
    cols,
    // Square canvas size
    canvasSize = 600,
    resolution = 10;

let maxCellsPerRowCol = canvasSize / resolution;

let make2DArray = (cols, rows) => {
    let arr = new Array()

    for(let y = 0; y < cols; y++) {
        arr[y] = new Array();
        for(let x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
            let alive = Math.round(Math.random());
            arr[y][x] = new Cell(x, y, resolution, alive);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

function start() {
    canvas.width = canvasSize;
    canvas.height = canvasSize;
    cachedCanvas.width = canvasSize;
    cachedCanvas.height = canvasSize;
    rows = canvas.width / resolution;
    cols = canvas.height / resolution;
    grid = make2DArray(cols, rows);
    // console.table(grid)
}

function update() {
    let newGrid = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(grid))
    // Update the new grid based on the rules
    // for(var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    //     for(var j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
    //         let cell = grid[i][j];
    //         let newCell = newGrid[i][j];
    //         let neighbors = getNeighborsOfCell(grid, cell);
    //         let totalAliveNeighbors = getTotalAliveNeighbors(neighbors);

    //         if(cell.state == 1 && totalAliveNeighbors < 2) newCell.state = 0;
    //         if(cell.state == 1 && totalAliveNeighbors == 2 || totalAliveNeighbors == 3) newCell.state = 1;
    //         if(cell.state == 1 && totalAliveNeighbors > 3) newCell.state = 0;
    //         if(cell.state == 0 && totalAliveNeighbors == 3) newCell.state = 1;
    //     }
    // }
    prerender();
    draw();
    // Update the grid with the new grid
    grid = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newGrid))

}

function prerender() {
    // Pre-render the grid
    for(var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            let cell = grid[i][j];
            cell.computeNeighborsCoords();

            if(cell.state == 1) {
                cell.fillColor = "#000"
            } else {
                cell.fillColor = "#FFF"
            }

            cachedCtx.beginPath();
            cachedCtx.lineWidth = "1";
            cachedCtx.fillStyle = cell.fillColor;
            cachedCtx.strokeStyle = "black";
            cachedCtx.rect(cell.sx, cell.sy, cell.w, cell.h); 
            cachedCtx.fill()
            cachedCtx.stroke();
        }
    }
}

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(cachedCanvas, 0, 0)

    window.requestAnimationFrame(update);

}

start();
window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

Comment: `grid = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newGrid))` — only plain objects and arrays can be serialized and parsed as objects. You’ll lose the class prototype.

Comment: That explains why i am getting the error if i am loosing the prototype. Thank you for your time! I will try after i get some sleep. If i remove the parse and stringify methods, what do you propose i use instead to make a copy of an array of objects?